# AngularJS Unit Testing, Why is it useful?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I am learning AngularJS and there is this thing called "Unit Testing" which is mentioned on almost every page of the angularjs documentation.

The thing is, I can't really understand what the unit testing is. It really looks like it's unnecessary but it probably isn't.

Can somebody please explain why is it useful to spend time on writing unit tests? 
How can I benefit from it?

Comment: There are *millions* of pages touting the benefits of testing. Start here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose you have a project. On your project some features need to work. Traditionally people tested them. However, the problem with this is that whenever you change something in your code, you might ruin something. As a result, you need to test everything again and again after each change in your code. Now, that could be troublesome. If you have to conduct 10 tests after each change, then, after only 10 changes you need to execute 100 tests. That takes time. Time is money. Therefore, whenever you can define automatic tests, then instead of going over your test cases each and every time, you can define unit tests which will automatically tell you whether something is wrong. The difference between manual tests and unit tests is like the difference between calculating everything using pen and paper instead of using a calculator. Some tests cannot be automaticized, but whenever something can be tested automatically, you need to define unit tests for it.

Answer (score 1):

As a web developer, you have to accept the fact that you have no idea or control over how people will use your application. Once it hits the wild, all bets are off. Unit testing tells you if the code you wrote is actually doing what you think it is doing. This is necessary because the more complex an application gets, the harder it is to keep track of everything. Once the project goes beyond the age of 6 months, or grows beyond one developer, all bets are off when it comes to what you wrote being used the way you intended it. Unit tests help you pinpoint when something isn't right and solve the issue before the app is launched. Your tests are typically written once and then used over and over again. In fact, you should have more lines of tests than you have of code. Look at Angular, Ember, Backbone, jQuery. All of them utilize unit tests (thousands of them!) to make sure that they don't inadvertently kill some functionality while fixing a bug. Any application that goes beyond a variable declaration and a single function should have unit tests.

Time spent writing unit tests is never wasted. The same goes for end-2-end tests.

Answer (score 1):

Unit testing is a way of ensuring your programs fits its specifications.
You describe each unit for example a class and its methods. Then in tests you write what you expect them to do. Then you write the minimum amount of code to make the test pass.

So here you can see it helps you plan your development.

It also means if you come back to an old piece of code, a function or something. You change this code to make it work for something you've just written but in doing so you break one of the tests.

Here it helps you add new functionality without breaking existing code by making you stick to the rules you've set out before.

In large teams, it becomes even more useful when your code is interacting with code you may have never seen, written by someone else.